# Find unknown parameters of the function, if f(x) and x are given

Tags: machine-learning, math, linear-regression, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I need some help.
I have an equation:

*f(x) = ***a***cos(x) + (***b***sqrt(x) + ***c***tg(x))^2*,

where a, b, c are unknown parameters.
Also I have a few pairs of x -> f(x) like in Supervised ML problem.

How can I find parameters? I'm thinking of some numerical methods and linear regression, but actually I don't know what to do.

Comment: Your model is weird and seems "random". Unfortunately, due to the square, it is non-linear in a, b and c. Try least-squares fitting by Levenberg-Marquardt.

Answer (score 1):

The unknown parameters would minimize the sum of squared differences between computed function values and observed function values.

You could define such a sum of squared errors in *Excel* and use [Excel Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) to minimize it.

From a Python program, you could try [Scipy fsolve](https://www.pythonpool.com/scipy-fsolve/).

Comment: I need to do it on Python. So, my first suggestion was to describe function, define a dict with x->f(x) and set a random interval. And then search for needful parameters using MSE. But I'm not sure how is this algorithm optimal.

Comment: You would probably get better results using the miminization, least squares or fitting routines of scipy.optimize. The non-linear solver `fsolve` is not quite appropriate for over-determined systems.